# C# Saving Panel as image at Multithread

Tags: c#, multithreading, image, panel

I don't have any problem saving panel as image with UI thread but i have only a black rectangle when i save this panel at another thread except UI thread :

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
        {
            if (panel1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                panel1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {
                    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));

                });
                Bitmap bb = bmp.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 1016, 648), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                bb.Save(@"C:\sample.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }
            else
            {
              panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
              Bitmap bb = bmp.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 1016, 648), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
              bb.Save(@"C:\sample.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }

        }
```

This problem is related with locking mechanism? Or how can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in `BeginInvoke`, the function has not ended when the save function already started. Try use `Invoke`.

Comment: @Julo,you're exactly right. It worked. How can i sign your answert as accepted answer?

Comment: Comments can not be marked as answer. Therefore I posted a answer with a more detailed description why it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Universal answer *(with explanation)*:

`BeginInvoke` is function that send a message 'this function should be executed in different thread' and then directly leaves to continue execution in current thread.

The function is executed at a later time, when the target thread has 'free time' *(messages posted before are processed)*.

When you need the result of the function, use `Invoke`. The `Invoke` function is 'slower', or better to say it blocks current thread until the executed function finishes. *(I newer really tested this in C#, but it s possible, that the `Invoke` function is prioritized; e.g. when you call `BeginInvoke` and directly after it `Invoke` to the same thread, the function from `Invoke` will probably be executed before the function from `BeginInvoke`.)*

Use this alternative when you need the function to be executed before the next instruction are processed *(when you need the result of the invoked function)*.

**Simple *(tl;dr)***: When you need to need to only set a value *(e.g. set text of edit box)*, use `BeginInvoke`, but when you need a result *(e.g. get text from edit box)* use always `Invoke`.

In your case you need the result *(bitmap to be drawn)* therefore you need to wait for the function to end. *(There are also other possible options, but in this case the simple way is the better way.)*

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.