# C# - Threads don't work

Tags: c#

I made proxy checker and for some reason it's working very slow, I tried to use 100 Threads but still working very slow.

How can I make it work much faster?

Code:

```
WebProxy myproxy;


        Parallel.ForEach(
PROXIES,
new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 200 },
proxy =>
{
    try
    {
        myproxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.co.il/");
        request.Timeout = TimeOut;
        request.Proxy = myproxy;
        WebResponse re = request.GetResponse();
        this.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(proxy + "\r\n");
        });
        Good++;
        this.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            label3.Text = "Good: " + Good.ToString();
        });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Bad++;
        this.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            label4.Text = "Bad: " + Good.ToString();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to change `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke`. You can see the reasons here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49434697/2826535

Comment: what was logic for _I tried to use 100 Threads but still working very slow._ why 100 and not 1000 ?

Comment: `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 200` - You understand you don't have that many cores available, right?  Reducing the number to the number of available cores would start to speed things up.

Comment: @john That's not necessarily good advice, this is IO bound work, not CPU bound work.

Comment: so, how can I make it work faster?

Comment: @john What Rotem says is true. It's very likely that each single request idles for the response time, sitting there doing nothing. Then it performs some minimal computation like setting a label text. Serializing that simply adds all response times, leaving all cores idle. Fully parallelizing that, by contrast, sends all queries in quick succession, and then waits *for all of them at once*. When the bulk of them arrives, again in quick succession, there will be potential CPU overload, but no big harm done by the overhead of, say, 1000 threads instead of 4, compared to the 1/250 waiting time.

Comment: @Peter A. Schneider how can I make it work faster? I changed it from 200 to 1000 but it still worked slow

Comment: @Peter & Rotem, apologies. I wasn't aware that `WebRequest` had an async method, so I assumed that `GetResponse()` was simply blocking the thread.

Comment: @CodeLikeAl3oSS have you tried the change from first comment? `Invoke` can be very slow, since it waits for response from another thread. It is still slow after the change? Then you need to measure times (e.g. `StopWatch`) for operations.

Comment: I changed it to BeginInvoke, but it still work slow

Comment: how long is your timeout?

Comment: my timeout is 3000

Comment: In internet communication, there are things, that can not be accelerated on your side. The delay can be on 'server side' *(or the path, e. g. proxy)*. One application had initialisation time up to 20 seconds. When I tracked it down, it was a SOAP request on server. After removing this web-request the initialisation was no more than a second. *(The web server was already in stalled state; no longer updated and no new information cloud be obtained from it; in my case it was the best choice to remove it, unfortunately that is not your case.)*

Comment: then what can I do? maybe I can change the url?

Comment: @CodeLikeAl3oSS Exceptions in a loop can also slow down the process e.g. see http://www.chinhdo.com/20080226/try-catch-blocks-performance/

Comment: but I have to use try-catch to check the proxies

Comment: Try using an HttpClient like [Restsharp](http://restsharp.org/) where you can check the statusCode of the request instead of throwing exceptions